# Is it possible to create events (Temperature, humidity, noises) in the environment of a WSN in OMNET++ with INET++

Tags: events, sensors, environment, omnet++, inet

Is it possible to create events (Temperature, humidity, noises) in the environment of a WSN in OMNET++ with INET++
I would like to create a wsn where the nodes can actually measure their environment and send the data through the network. Does anybody know whether that is possible with OMNET++

I looked through the Manual but can't find anything on this topic and I starting to have the suspicion that its not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Being a network simulation framework INET is mostly dealing with network communication only, however there are some areas which are related to this and handled also by INET (node mobility, battery consumption etc.)

On the other hand, it is totally possible to create a model where various sensors (that are actually 'applications' in the OSI stack) communicate with a central component that represents the environment. That central environment component could send various events to the sensors that contain physical values. The sensor app would receive that (i.e. measure the value) and translate that into network call.

This is very similar how the wireless communication is modeled where there is a central component representing the electromagnetic spectrum and that component directly passes reception events to the nodes (taking into account the node position).

Long story short. It is possible, but there is nothing currently in INET that does that. You have to write your own code.

ps: If your requirement is just to occasionally change a value at given time, then I would take a look at the ScenarioManager component. That allows you to create a file in advance which encodes various parameter values for various modules at specific times. Parameter changes can be detected by the module. This is quite limited however, so you probably need to write your own model. It really depends how you want to describe the environment.